# Magento 1.9.0.1 compatible with PHP 5.6.5 and MySQL 5.6

Tags: database, ce-1.9.0.1, php-5.6

Is it possible to use Magento-1.9.0.1 with PHP 5.6.5 and MySQL 5.6?

Comment: yes it compatible use  Magento-1.9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It compatible use Magento-1.9.0.1 with PHP 5.6.5 and MySQL 5.6

source : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

System Requirements for Magento Enterprise Edition and Community Edition (As per magento's documentation)

Magento requires a LAMP or LNMP stack

**Operating System**  Linux x86-64

**Web Server**  Apache 2.x,Nginx 1.7.x

**Database**  MySQL 5.6 (Oracle or Percona)

**PHP**

**Magento CE 1.9.2 and later, Magento EE 1.14.2 and later:**

PHP 5.6.x,
PHP 5.4.x,
PHP 5.5.x

**Earlier Magento versions:**

PHP 5.4.x,PHP 5.5.x

Comment: Isnt your answer a discrepancy? You wrote it is possible but your quote says no:

_Magento CE 1.9.2 and later, Magento EE 1.14.2 and later:

PHP 5.6.x, PHP 5.4.x, PHP 5.5.x

Earlier Magento versions:

PHP 5.4.x,PHP 5.5.x_

Comment: 1.9.0.1 is compatible  with PHP 5.6.5 and MySQL 5.6 but is per magento documentation it's not.